# Coming of age fantasy book- main character trains by dying fighting demons

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

In this world there are two distinct classes, the upper class being generally bigger and faster than the lower and magicians belong to the upper class regardless of their race. Magicians can access an another dimension that demons exist.

The first book starts with the main character aiming for admittance in a school for warriors at the same time his/a girlfriend is found out to be a magician which puts her in a different social class than him. he convinces a famous lower class warrior to admit him into his group

As he gradually trains with this group he dedicates himself completely and progresses quickly until he as a dual wielding swordsman and is better than all the upper class cadets.

The magicians can cast a beam of light that transports people to an alternate reality overlying their own, where demons live. In this world these demons kill you, but when the beam of light is stopped you return to your body as if nothing has happened. They use this to disable their enemies. The lead character gets access to this world and to improve his swordsmanship he enters this world to train while every else is asleep, dying over and over again to try and be the best.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: He dies fighting demons?

Comment: Hi Chris. Do you mean that part of the training is fighting a demon, losing and dying, then being revived again?

Comment: Please clarify the role of demons in the story within the body of your question, right now I'm confused as to where they come in.

Comment: Are you possibly conflating things in the Drow series featuring Drizz't Do'Urden? Magicians are in a special caste, Drizz't basically rules the roost even as a first year cadet, fighting with two scimitars. Menzobaranzann, Melee-Magthere, any of that ring a bell?

Comment: Could it possibly be: [The Warrior Heir](https://www.teenreads.com/reviews/the-warrior-heir)?

Comment: not the drizzt do'Urden series although i do enjoy the series and not the warrior heir,

Answer (score 6):

[*The Rage of Dragons*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/41952489-the-rage-of-dragons) - Evan Winter

Goodreads:

> The Omehi people have been fighting an unwinnable fight for almost two hundred years. Their society has been built around war and only war. The lucky ones are born gifted. One in every two thousand women has the power to call down dragons. One in every hundred men is able to magically transform himself into a bigger, stronger, faster killing machine.
>
> Everyone else is fodder, destined to fight and die in the endless war. Young, gift-less Tau knows all this, but he has a plan of escape. He's going to get himself injured, get out early, and settle down to marriage, children, and land. Only, he doesn't get the chance. Those closest to him are brutally murdered, and his grief swiftly turns to anger. Fixated on revenge, Tau dedicates himself to an unthinkable path. He'll become the greatest swordsman to ever live, a man willing to die a hundred thousand times for the chance to kill the three who betrayed him.